# how to design arc in html

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hello guys.
I want to design an arc similar first rectangle (red one).
As you see result in green rectangle. I try to use border-radius in CSS and I did not get a good result.

```
border-bottom-right-radius: 5em;
border-top-right-radius: 5em;
```

I desire a arc like first rectangle.

thanks.

Comment: You can read about creating different shapes using css here : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: HTML is a text markup language. If you want a graphics markup language, try SVG.

Comment: Also `-webkit-clip-path: ellipse(25% 50% at 5% 50%);
clip-path: ellipse(25% 50% at 5% 50%);`
You can try this code

Comment: Checkout this website for such patterns : http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin alluded to, you can get whatever exact shape you want with an SVG. But depending on your case, that might be overcomplicating things a bit.

You can get a shape pretty similar to your screenshot just by using a double border radius.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

As Envision mentioned, you can also use `clip-path` to achieve something like this, but [browser support for that is poor](http://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path) right now.